# Angular 11 unable to resolve dependency tree while installing node modules

Tags: angular

I have seen lot of post regarding this topic, but that wasn't helpful for me,as my scenario is quite different in terms of modules and libraries and that's the reason behind creating this thread, well I have configured a jenkins pipeline job which is trying to perform `npm install`, and it encountered `unable to resolve dependency tree`, the snapshot for the same has been attached.

[image]

It has nothing to do with jenkins, because I have already tried to install the same using command line utility and here also I got the dependency not resolved error.

[image]

I am not able to figured it out, what went wrong while resolving the `@coreui`
I have also tried to install modules by using `--legacy-peer-deps` switch, but that was also not working for me.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@coreui/coreui-free-angular-admin-template",
  "version": "2.11.2",
  "description": "CoreUI Free Angular 11 Admin Template",
  "author": {
    "name": "Łukasz Holeczek",
    "url": "http://holeczek.pl",
    "github": "https://github.com/mrholek",
    "twitter": "https://twitter.com/lukaszholeczek"
  },
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "Andrzej Kopański",
      "url": "https://github.com/xidedix"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": "https://coreui.io/angular",
  "copyright": "Copyright ©2021 Netlink. All Rights Reserved.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --common-chunk --vendor-chunk --optimization --progress",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^11.2.5",
    "@coreui/angular": "^2.11.2",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@coreui/icons-angular": "1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.3",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^5.0.8",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.47",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^25.2.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^25.2.1",
    "angular-crumbs": "^3.0.1",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "filepond": "^4.27.1",
    "filepond-plugin-file-encode": "^2.1.9",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size": "^2.2.2",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "^1.2.5",
    "filepond-plugin-image-crop": "^2.0.4",
    "filepond-plugin-image-edit": "^1.6.1",
    "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation": "^1.0.9",
    "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.6.4",
    "filepond-plugin-image-resize": "^2.0.7",
    "filepond-plugin-image-transform": "^3.7.3",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng-block-ui": "^2.1.8",
    "ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-filepond": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-filter-pipe": "^2.1.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-show-hide-password": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.5.5",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.33",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.13",
    "npm": ">= 6"
  }
}
```

**EDITS:**

[image]

**npm run ng -- --version**

[image]

Comment: Remove font-awesome from package.json and try an npm install again..?

Comment: are you talking about these three `"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0","@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35","@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",`

Comment: At least the first one.. that doesn’t seem compatible with the ng version you use.

Comment: please see my edits, it seems there is something wrong between angular and Node, they are not complementing each other, its seems suspicious, isn't all those issues arises because of this.

Comment: Using angular cli 12, the project has packages for angular 11, and title says angular 8....

Comment: Corrected the same, thanks jason, I forgot to edit

Answer (score 0):

`@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome` is used with `^` version operator in the `package.json`. This means, that npm is allowed to choose the latest minor version. At `@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome` the minor version determines the compatibility with Angular, as the compatibility tabel describes:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#compatibility-table

As the latest `@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome` version is `0.9.x` which might not be compatible with Angular `12.x.x`.

This means, that for Angular `11.x.x` version I suggest to use `@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome` version `0.8.0` or `~0.8.0`. In the last one `~` allows patch version change.

If you change this version, you might need to check the compatibility with the other `fontawesome` thirdparties as well. And if required, their version needs to be aligned as well.

Comment: Okay, So I am digging somewhere to know about the current version of Angular and the Node, is all these craps happening because of this, because I got a warning. `Warning: The current version of Node (16.6.1) is not supported by Angular.` Please see my edits

Comment: Wait, you are on a wrong path. `ng --version` in the commandline returns you the Angular CLI version of the globally installed Angular CLI.  Your global Angular CLI version is `12.2.0` but in your project is `^11.2.4` used. To see the Angular CLI version of your project run `npm run ng -- --version`. This is very important, because there is a major version difference between your project and your global Angular CLI version, which can result in different Node.js version requirements.

Comment: Hm.. that is really strange, based on the above `package.json` the `npm run ng -- --version` command should have returned an `11.x.x` Angular version. But it returned `12.x.x`, which should not be the case. I suggest to remove the `node_modules` in the project and call an `npm install`, maybe the dependencies are messed up currently in `node_modules`.

Comment: `node_modules` aren't there because of earlier failure of `npm install`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. If there is no node_modules, the global angular cli version is displayed in the project as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236420/discussion-between-user9634982-and-milan-tenk).